# Java.lang.verify Error in Android

Tags: java, android, addthis

I am trying to integrate *AddThisSdk* with my project. My project name is **AddThisDemo**. The AddThis sdk comes as a project. I have included it as a library in my project. I have also added the required jar file for OAuth (signpost and commomsHttp). When I run this project, it results in a force close. The error showing is given below:

```
07-24 10:35:45.470: E/AndroidRuntime(234): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234): java.lang.VerifyError: com.addthis.demo.HomeActivity
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-24 10:35:45.490: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone point out what is the cause or can anyone tell me when *java.lang.verify* error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

put the entry of this "HomeActivity" in your manifest.xml file and try again... may be it works....

Comment: If you are using ADT 17 or above,you cannot just add dependent libraries directly.Instead add all libraries in a specific folder called libs,eventhough you added directly using project->properties->addExternal jars/add jars.For me it fixed my problem
    
    Remarks: When i researched on Java.lang.Verify Error, i came to know that, it can be caused due to variety of reasons.So ensure that your problem is the same as i have experienced

Comment: And don't forget to mark the JAR file as "exported" in java build path dialog. :)